# Do Foundation Walls Cracked on Old Home Need Help?

Tags: repair, foundation, inspection

I bought my first house 3 years ago. The unfinished basement had cracks down the walls, some stepping down the bricks, others horizontal. The home inspector (used realtor's inspector) at the time said it wasn't a big deal and was common (home was built in the 60s).

My wife had someone come take a look at it today. He wants to brace the walls, remove drywall in the finished basement and brace all that, build in a drain system for the wall, and then dig the front of the home out to brace the corners externally on steel posts.

I believe the realtor's inspector and the basement repair guy both have significant conflicts of interest on what is actually right for my basement. Pretty sure the inspector breezed over stuff for an easy paycheck. And I'm not convinced I need to repair my entire basement. But I don't know enough about this to determine which way to go. So asking the good people on the internet who have no vested interest in my basement's well-being seems like the best route to go here.

Suggestions?

[image: horizontal crack]
[image: stepping]
[image: vertical and horizontal]
[image: offset at bottom of wall]

Comment: Pictures of the cracks will help.  Does the basement get wet/have water coming in?  Place marks at the cracks and measure them exactly.  Measure again in a month or two.  No change then not much of a problem, if changing, then contractor might be right, but get more quotes.

Comment: Hire a structural engineer to come in and offer their unbiased opinion.  You'll pay them for their time, but there will be no hidden agenda to want to get more business or any conflict of interest.

Comment: If you are in no hurry, a simple way to monitor the cracks is to draw lines (using a marker) across the cracks in several locations, number the lines, and then measure and record the crack width. Repeat the measuring in a scheduled time span and note the change in crack width

Comment: You're right about the inspector. They occasionally provide useful information, but generally they scare you to justify their existence. In this case I suspect they were right, but we can't possibly say from the almost nothing we know about your basement. Please see [ask], the [help], and take the [tour], then consider reformulating to ask about the actual problem rather than whether one person we don't know or the other is lying.

Comment: Horizontal cracking sets off a bit of an alarm bell in my mind. The top of a basement wall is typically braced by the house framing. The bottom is typically braced well at its interface to the floor. Horizontal cracking suggests that the wall isn't strong enough in bending between the top and bottom supports to fight the soil. I would use a long level or string line to look for a bulge halfway down the wall to confirm (or not) the bending weakness theory. The step pattern cracking typically indicates settling, a far less significant issue.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I've added some pictures to show the cracks. We did have water come in during a massive rainstorm, though the gutters on the roof were overflooded straight above it. And thanks for the patient responses. Still learning how to use stack exchange.

Comment: What is that bottom picture? Has the upper block slid across the lower block or something? If you trace the ledge created by that block overhang across the wall, does the ledge disappear at the corner? Does it gradually taper to zero before then? Is that same ledge everywhere in the basement and at that elevation? I would look at the corner for evidence of whether that's a construction defect going back to day 1 versus a developing problem. And do you know if that CMU wall is fully grouted? As in, are each of the cells filled with concrete?

Comment: An engineer may spec an upgrade to modern standards, and that could be one heckuva upgrade. Do you live in an earthquake area? How thick are your CMU blocks? What's the distance from the slab up to the underside of your ceiling joists. How much of that height has soil against it? Is the soil a gravel or sand with decent drainage? Or when you rub it between a couple of fingers is there pretty significant slickness? (I'm trying check your block size against Table 404.1.1(1) below [IRC R404.1.1](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-4-foundations#IRC2021P2_Pt03_Ch04_SecR404.1.1).)

Comment: If an engineer's fix calls for installing rebar in addition to grouting cells, I would explore the possibility of sizing interior wood walls to buttress the existing CMU wall as part of a larger "finishing the basement" scope. That could convert the wall's "maximum unsupported wall height" to zero.

Comment: Those could be considered cosmetic cracks, not structural. It look like the foundation on which the wall sits is solid without cracks. If it going to make you sleep better get a structural inspector.

Comment: @Traveler, take another look at the bottom pic. I'm pretty sure that that's a shear failure.

Comment: @popham looking, I do not see what you see, the concrete foundation part looks fine to me

Comment: @Traveler, the bottom course is also CMU. It's not a concrete stem wall or something. Note the head joint. The 2nd course has the bed joint mortar stuck to the bottom of it. It's flatness with a hiccup at the head joint indicates that it was shaped into a flat line like that by the 1st course right below it. The faces of these two courses were aligned at some point. Hmm. Maybe you're right, though. It almost looks like the forms were left on the lower bit until the masonry was installed above, where stripping a form with a joint at my proposed head joint could have left that ledge.

Comment: Get a second quote, from someone who can see the problem, rather than asking a virtual audience.

Comment: @popham , the bottom pic is the bottom of the wall at its center from outer edge. It does taper back together as you follow to the corner, making me think it has slid. I think the advice to have a structural inspector take a look makes a lot of sense. Thank you all for your quick responses and great advice.

Comment: The cracks don't look to be significant... IF they've been there for years and aren't getting any bigger/wider. Especially if there isn't any water coming in. Monitor the width and as long as it isn't getting worse, get an unbiased professional to render an opinion instead of a realtor inspector or someone who makes their living fixing basements.

Answer (score 2):

This is an appropriate time to bring in a structural engineer, ideally from an engineering firm that does no construction operations. I had similar-sounding cracks and water intrusion in my century home. It was flagged as worth investigation by the inspector I hired, but not likely to be a problem. The structural engineer I hired agreed that the cracks were not a problem, and that the house has a solid foundation that needs no work. And the water intrusion turned out to be a blocked gutter drain line.

So my advice: bring in a structural engineer. The few hundred dollars you pay them for the inspection should provide peace of mind, and maybe you'll end up hiring the basement repair person after all.

Comment: You might also look up a geotechnical specialist. If there's a buck to be saved by looking hard at the soil and water, he'll be more likely to save it for you. If the company has bios on its website, I would look for a place with a structural specialist and a geotech specialist.

Comment: Nice call popham.